# Appcelerator Titanium: Controlling Views Height and Top Automatically

Tags: javascript, titanium

```
var Section1 = Titanium.UI.createView({
    top:0,
    height: 'auto',
});


var Section2 = Titanium.UI.createView({
    top:0,
    height: 'auto',
});
```

I have two views and these two views has some buttons and TextFields which comes dyanmically. How can i control the Section 2 that it does not over lap the Section 1 View when its height gets increased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way, but I had a similar issue recently, which I tentatively solved like so

```
var Section1 = Titanium.UI.createView({
    top:0,
    height: 'auto',
});

// Add other views to Section1

var Section2 = Titanium.UI.createView({
    top: Section1.toImage().height,
    height: 'auto',
});
```

I think in your case the height will only be accurate after you've added your other views and objects to it.

Comment: FYI, the 'auto' value for size properties has been deprecated since TiSDK version 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding your views directly to the Ti.UI.currentWindow then you can just set layout of the Ti.UI.currentWindow to 'vertical' and the heights will automatically adjust

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.layout = 'vertical';
```

Comment: There are potential performance issues associated with complex views with the vertical or horizontal layout modes. I have ended up recoding my app to use the composite view with specific left and top settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ti.UI.createView({ 
            layout : 'vertical',
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE
});
```